# DNS-Server is not set when setting fixed, predictable network interface-names

Tags: networking, network-interface

I am currently working on an embedded system, which uses linux as the underlying system. Due to technical reasons, I have to set fixed interface names based on the mac-address of the network-adapters. By adding this configuration-lines for udev, I have 2 network-adapters, named nic0, nic1. This works perfectly, the naming is always the same, based on the mac-address:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="11:11:11:11:11:11", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="nic0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="22:22:22:22:22:22", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="nic1"
```

The IP-configuration of nic0 is static. The IP-configuration for nic1 is provided by a DHCP-server. See the "/etc/network/interfaces":

```
auto nic0
iface nic0 inet static
  address 10.0.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto nic1
iface nic1 inet dhcp
```

Unfurtunately after rebooting the system, no dns-servers have been set at all (not the static, not the ones provided by the DHCP-server). This is really strange because other informations provided by the DHCP-Server are set (e.g. IP-address, subnet-mask, broadcast etc...).

The file "/etc/resolv.conf" is empty after rebooting.

If I remove/comment out again the predictable intefaces-names for udev, the adapters are named eth0, eth1 (arbitrary assignment though) and everything works fine, the dns-server is set by the value provided by the DHCP-server.

If I start "dhclient" after booting the system, the DNS-servers are also set properly.

What am I doing wrong so that the adapters are not set at bootime? What's going on here?

Thanks!